# How to select another gameobject with same mouse button (first selection !=null?) ? in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, click, gameobject

I have a script that logs the first gameobject I left-click on (works fine) but I can't seem to figure out how to log a second different gameobject with another click of same mouse button. (currently my first click logs the same gameobject in both slots, probably something easy I've overlooked). I want to reserve right mouse button to reset the selections.

Here's my script:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        RaycastHit hit;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
            if (firstClick == null) {
                if (hit.transform != null) { // if object is hit

                    firstClick = (hit.transform.gameObject); // hit object name is stored
                    print (firstClick);
                }
            }
        }

        //click second selection
        if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
            if (firstClick != null && secondClick == null) {
                if (hit.transform != null) { // if object is hit

                    secondClick = (hit.transform.gameObject); // hit object name is stored
                    print (secondClick);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `Physics.Raycast` specifically always returns the first game object the ray hits. It doesn't care that you said "I already know about this one."

Comment: Ahh, well that's disappointing. I guess I'll change it to left click first selection, right click second selection and left again to reset.

Comment: Here's the code for anyone wanting to do something similar: First selection same as in question. //click second selection
  if (firstClick != null && secondClick == null) {
   if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (1)) {
    RaycastHit hit;
    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay (Input.mousePosition);

   if (Physics.Raycast (ray, out hit)) {
      if (hit.transform != null) { // if object is hit

       secondClick = (hit.transform.gameObject); // hit object name is stored
       print (secondClick);
      }
     }
    }
  }

Comment: And the reset part:                                     //Reset selections
  if (firstClick !=null && secondClick != null && Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
   firstClick = null; //position is now reset
   secondClick = null; //reset
  }
 }
}

Comment: Also, `RaycastAll` exists.